# Select count by datetime

Tags: sql-server, select

How can I select the current row count of the table until the current month, and to group count values by last 6 months?

Sample data:

```
Id     CreatedTime      PersonId       MonthValue
1      2015-03-01       1              100
2      2015-03-15       5              200 
3      2015-04-19       7              400 
...
...
...
980    2016-07-22       1349           100
```

Wish to group row count in output like:

```
Date       Total
07/2016    331
06/2016    277
05/2016    145
04/2016    100    
03/2016    69
02/2016    57
```

Comment: can you show the schema of the table you are querying with some sample data please?

Comment: @Tanner Sorry for lack of info, I've added it now, but I've got the correct answer from vercelli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an auxiliary table with dates:

```
;with dateaux as (select eomonth(GETDATE()) as d, -1 as lev union all
                 select eomonth(dateadd(month,lev,getdate())), lev-1 from dateaux where lev >-6)
select format(d, 'MM/yyyy'), count(*)
 from dateaux join table1 t on dateaux.d >= t.mydate
 group by format(d, 'MM/yyyy')
```

dateaux output would look like this:

```
d           lev
2016-07-31  -1
2016-06-30  -2
2016-05-31  -3
2016-04-30  -4
2016-03-31  -5
2016-02-29  -6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT  LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),[DateField],112),6) as [Date],
        COUNT(*) as [Total]
FROM YourTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(month,[DateField],GETDATE()) < 6
GROUP BY LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),[DateField],112),6) 
ORDER BY LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),[DateField],112),6) DESC
```

On my dummy data with 12 month I get:

```
Date    Total
201607  207
201606  270
201605  279
201604  270
201603  279
201602  261
```

If you need cumulative data:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),[DateField],112),6) as [Date],
        COUNT(*) as [Total]
FROM YourTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(month,[DateField],GETDATE()) < 6
GROUP BY LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),[DateField],112),6) 
)

SELECT  c1.[Date],
        SUM(c2.[Total]) as [Total]
FROM cte c1
INNER JOIN cte c2
    ON c1.[Date] >= c2.[Date]
GROUP BY c1.[Date], c1.[Total]
ORDER BY c1.[Date] DESC
```

Output:

```
Date    Total
201607  1566
201606  1359
201605  1089
201604  810
201603  540
201602  261
```

Comment: This query will give amount by month, but not the cummulative

Comment: @vercelli perhaps state in the question that you want a cumulative count, otherwise how are we supposed to know?

Comment: @vercelli sorry, thought you were OP, that point is directed to OP if that's what he's after.

Comment: @Tanner that's ok, It's clear to me that OP it's looking for cummulative count ("until the current month") but we can all agree that the question is lacking some more info

Comment: @vercelli it is not that clear but I add query to get cumulative count

Comment: @gofr1 Looks good to me, but I kind of prefer my approach since we don't know how big is his table, so I'm using an auxliary CTE table with only 6 rows with dates.

Comment: @vercelli I use auxiliary CTE with dummy data too (~5k rows with date, int). The solution is nice :) I must note that you query will work in SQL Server 2012 and up. I don't remember `EOMONTH` and `FORMAT` functions in 2008 (R2)

Comment: @vercelli Thank you, your answer is what I was looking for, I'm sorry for lack of details in my question (was writing in a hurry).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the data you've shown is the desired output, and that you have a table with dates and values. Here's a sample of how you can achieve something similar to your desired output:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sales
    (
      OrderDate DATETIME ,
      SaleValue DECIMAL(5, 2)
    )

INSERT  INTO #Sales ( OrderDate , SaleValue )
    SELECT  '20160701' , 125.00
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  '20160702' , 255.00
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  '20160621' , 75.00
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  '20160522' , 95.00
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  '20160404' , 410.00
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  '20160412' , 207.00 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  '20160415' , 107.00 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  '20160313' , 10.00 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  '20160207' , 179.00 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  '20160125' , 237.00 

SELECT  YEAR(OrderDate) OrderYear ,
        MONTH(OrderDate) OrderMonth ,
        CAST(MONTH(OrderDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' 
      + CAST(YEAR(OrderDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) OrderDate ,
        COUNT(SaleValue) Total
FROM    #Sales
WHERE   YEAR(OrderDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())
        AND MONTH(OrderDate) >= MONTH(DATEADD(mm, -5, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate) ,
        MONTH(OrderDate)

DROP TABLE #Sales
```

Produces:

```
OrderYear   OrderMonth  OrderDate   Total
2016        2           2/2016      1
2016        3           3/2016      1
2016        4           4/2016      3
2016        5           5/2016      1
2016        6           6/2016      1
2016        7           7/2016      2
```